# AttributeError: Assignment not allowed to composite field "task" in protocol message object

Tags: python, protocol-buffers

I'm using protocol-buffers python lib to send data,but it's have some problems, so

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_message.py", line 17, in <module>
    ptask.task = task
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\google\protobuf\internal\python_message.py", line
513, in setter
AttributeError: Assignment not allowed to composite field "_task" in protocol message object.
```

the src as follows:

proto file:

```
message task {
    required int32 id = 1;
    required string msg = 2;
}

message task_info {
    required task task = 1;
}
```

python code:

```
task = yacc.task()
task.id = 1000
task.msg = u"test"
ptask = yacc.task_info() 
ptask.task = task # this line happen the runtime error
```

Answer (score 46, accepted):

I don't know *protocol-buffers* but I took a look at [the docs](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/python-generated) and it says:

> You cannot assign a value to an embedded message field. Instead,
>   assigning a value to any field within the child message implies
>   setting the message field in the parent.

So I'm assuming this should work:

```
task = yacc.task()
task.id = 1000
task.msg = u"test"
ptask = yacc.task_info() 
ptask.task.id = task.id
ptask.task.msg = task.msg
```

Comment: This is the [section of the docs](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/python-generated#embedded_message) where it talks about that. It also mentions the `CopyFrom` method.

Answer (score 139):

Try [CopyFrom](https://googleapis.dev/python/protobuf/3.11.2/google/protobuf/message.html#google.protobuf.message.Message.CopyFrom):

```
ptask.task.CopyFrom(task)
```

Comment: @Cu2S golden rule of StackExchange: always at least read the first *two* answers!

Comment: This is THE answer. The `MergeFrom` mentioned in other answers can also be useful sometimes.

Answer (score 23):

I'm new to protocol-buffers too and faced with the same problem. I've found [this method](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/python/google.protobuf.message.Message-class#MergeFrom) helpful.

I think it should work:

```
task = yacc.task()
task.id = 1000
task.msg = u"test"
ptask = yacc.task_info() 
ptask.task.MergeFrom(task)
```

Comment: CopyFrom() calls MergeFrom() after Clearing the object