# How to assign to repeated field?

Tags: python, protocol-buffers

I am using protocol buffers in python and I have a `Person` message

```
repeated uint64 id
```

but when I try to assign a value to it like:

```
person.id = [1, 32, 43432]
```

I get an error: `Assigment not allowed for repeated field "id" in protocol message object`
How to assign a value to a repeated field ?

Answer (score 174, accepted):

As per the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/python-generated?csw=1#fields), you aren't able to directly assign to a repeated field. In this case, you can call `extend` to add all of the elements in the list to the field.

```
person.id.extend([1, 32, 43432])
```

Comment: Similarly, for adding a single value, use `append()`, e.g. `person.id.append(1)`. This applies for **any** *protobuf* `repeated` fields.

Comment: `append` doesn't work if the field is a message type rather than a raw type (like string, int32, etc). `extend` does work for message types.

Comment: If you want to overwrite a repeated message type field then you need to delete first and then extend. `del person.siblings[:]` `person.siblings.extend([Person(), Person()])`

Comment: https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/python-generated?csw=1#repeated-message-fields

Comment: remember to pass in the arguments to extend as an array (or list), wrap them with brackets if you need to!

Comment: I'd just like to mention that if you're adding a single element, append does not work if the field you're adding is itself a message. In this case, you should use the method `add`.
https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/python-generated#repeated-message-fields

Comment: Also related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18376190/attributeerror-assignment-not-allowed-to-composite-field-task-in-protocol-mes

Comment: It's probably worth pointing out now that the comments indicating that `append` does not work if the field is a message type, are no longer correct. The documentation linked in the comments now shows the use of `append` in such cases and I have confirmed it works. `add` and `extend` of course also work.

Comment: I'm trying to use extend , and I keep getting the message "TypeError: Not a cmessage"

Answer (score 62):

If you don't want to *extend* but overwrite it completely, you can do:

```
person.id[:] = [1, 32, 43432]
```

This approach will also work to clear the field entirely:

```
del person.id[:]
```

Comment: For repeated composite types, you can not  use person.id[:] = [xxx] to assign replace. You have to first delete them all and then extend

Answer (score 13):

For repeated composite types this is what worked for me.

```
del person.things[:]
person.things.extend([thing1, thing2, ..])
```

taken from these comments
[How to assign to repeated field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23726335/how-to-assign-to-repeated-field#comment98134436_47748153)
[How to assign to repeated field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23726335/how-to-assign-to-repeated-field#comment83313602_23726417)

Answer (score 10):

After loosing a lot of sleep trying to get a basic example for repeated fields working, I finally got it.

**The problem:**

- Create a calculator.py with two functions, square and multiplier.
- Using GRPC, create a Proto file for the same.
- Write a server, a client.
- Run the server, and run the client to get correct results.

**The Proto file:**

```
syntax = "proto3";

message Number {
    int32 value = 1;
}

message NumList {
    string name = 1;
    repeated Number nums = 2;
}

service Calculator {
    rpc Multiplier(NumList) returns (Number) {}
    rpc Square(Number) returns (Number) {}
}
```

Now the square part is easy, but for the Multiplier, I wanted to pass a list of Numbers (as in Number type as defined in the proto file).

The problem was with the **repeated** field. And here is the ultimate solution in short.

**The solution:**

```
import grpc

# import the generated classes
import calculator_pb2
import calculator_pb2_grpc
# open a gRPC channel
channel = grpc.insecure_channel('localhost:50051')

# create a stub (client)
stub = calculator_pb2_grpc.CalculatorStub(channel)
num_list = calculator_pb2.NumList()
num_list.name = 'MyFirstList'
n1 = num_list.nums.add()
n2 = num_list.nums.add()
n3 = num_list.nums.add()
n1.value = 10
n2.value = 20
n3.value = 30

assert len(num_list.nums) == 3

response = stub.Multiplier(num_list)
print(response.value)
```

**The Calculator Multiplier function (because this needs to be shown):**

```
def multiplier(numlist, name):
    mul = 1
    for num in numlist:
        mul = mul * num.value
    print(f'Result of list {name}')
    return mul
```

*Hope this helps someone. Hope this is as descriptive as it should be.*

Comment: Is not it enough to use `repeated int32 nums = 2;` in the message `NumList`? if I am not wrong you want to make a collection of `int data`, eg : `[2,5,9]`. I have checked with `cpp` though.

Comment: This answer saves my day. This addresses the problem of composing a message with non-primitive repeated field in gRPC.