# How do I assign a oneof field on a protobuf message if the child message has no fields?

Tags: python, grpc, bigtable

I want to create a BigTable `DeleteFromRow` mutation. The proto for the `Mutation` and the `DeleteFromRow` look like this:

```
oneof mutation {
    // Set a cell's value.
    SetCell set_cell = 1;

    // Deletes cells from a column.
    DeleteFromColumn delete_from_column = 2;

    // Deletes cells from a column family.
    DeleteFromFamily delete_from_family = 3;

    // Deletes cells from the entire row.
    DeleteFromRow delete_from_row = 4;
  }
}

message DeleteFromRow {

}
```

In Python, you cannot directly instantiate a `DeleteFromRow` object and set the `delete_from_row` field of the `Mutation` to that object.

So this **does not work**:

```
request = bigtable_pb2.MutateRowRequest(table_name='tablename', row_key=row_key)
mutation = request.mutations.add()
mutation.delete_from_row = data_pb2.Mutation.DeleteFromRow()
```

As raised by other SO users (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18376190/attributeerror-assignment-not-allowed-to-composite-field-task-in-protocol-mes/22771612)), that results in a

```
AttributeError: Assignment not allowed to composite field "delete_from_row" in protocol message object.
```

According to the [protobuf docs](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/python-generated#oneof), you should set a oneof field by setting one of the child fields. So a `DeleteFromFamily` mutation should be created this way:

```
mutation.delete_from_family.family_name = 'some_family'
```

However, how do I do that for the `DeleteFromRow` message that has no fields?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you not using the official client?

Comment: Because it is not complete. It is an abstraction on top of this grpc implementation. In particular, when I wanted to read rows based on either a set of rowkeys or a set of rowkey prefixes, I switched to the underlying grpc client that allows you to do that in a single request.

Comment: Got it.  FWIW, we're working on that feature now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can initiate the `DeleteFromRow` object and create a mutation with the keyword argument `delete_from_row`:

```
dfr = data_pb2.Mutation.DeleteFromRow()
mutation = data_pb2.Mutation(delete_from_row=dfr)
```

While you cannot `add` or `append` this mutation to the repeated mutations field of a request (although it appears to me that that is what the docs says [here](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/python-generated?csw=1#repeated-fields)), you *can* `extend` it:

```
request = bigtable_pb2.MutateRowRequest(table_name='tablename', row_key=row_key)
request.mutations.extend([mutation])
```

Comment: Regarding that link to the docs: there is a difference between a `Repeated Field` and a `Repeated Message Field`. The latter has no `append` function - as documented.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Message.SetInParent](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/python/google.protobuf.message.Message-class.html#SetInParent):

> Mark this as present in the parent.
>
> This normally happens automatically when you assign a field of a sub-message, but sometimes you want to make the sub-message present while keeping it empty. If you find yourself using this, you may want to reconsider your design.

Example:

```
message Msg {
  oneof kind {
    int64 int_field = 1;
    EmptyMsg msg_field = 1;
  }
}

message EmptyMsg {}
```

```
msg = Msg()
print(msg.WhichOneof('kind'))  # None

msg.msg_field  # No-op (return EmptyMsg but don't set oneof field)
print(msg.WhichOneof('kind'))  # None

msg.msg_field.SetInParent()
print(v.WhichOneof('kind'))  # msg_field
```